# What is the parametric form of a square at an angle?

Tags: geometry, parametric

I need to plot a number of rectangles that are rotated at certain angles. For 'normal' rectangles, I would use a parametrization like: 
$x = x_0 + \frac{1}{2}w \ sgn(\cos{\theta})$, 
$y = y_0 + \frac{1}{2}w \ sgn(\sin{\theta})$, where $w$ is the width of the rectangle and $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$

Can I use something similar where I can use the angle as input?

Comment: Is ${\rm sgn}(x) = x/|x|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rotate the above by an angle $\psi$ then just apply the rotation to the $(x,y)$ coordinates

$$\begin{aligned}
 x &= x_0 + \tfrac{w}{2} \cos \psi\, {\rm sgn}(\cos \theta) - \tfrac{h}{2} \sin \psi\, {\rm sgn}(\sin \theta) \\
 y &= y_0 + \tfrac{w}{2} \sin \psi\, {\rm sgn}(\cos \theta) + \tfrac{h}{2} \cos \psi\, {\rm sgn}(\sin \theta)
\end{aligned} $$

where $w$ is the width  and $h$ the height of the rectangle.

Comment: Of course, that makes a lot of sense, just couldn't think of it. Thank you!